# Linking a .txt into Visual basic 2010 as a storage system

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a automatic chatbot that will pull random lines from a separate .txt so that I can have less bulky code. However I am finding it hard to locate a way of doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this isn't very clear if it isn't I am happy to clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the my.resources block? You find it under my project -> resources. Simply add your strings.
in your code, you can acess them like dim str= my.resources.xyz

Then build somewhere a new list along this lines:

```
    Dim mylist As New List(Of String)
    Dim ResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
    For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In ResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
        If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is String Then
            Debug.WriteLine(Dict.Key) 'outputting resource name
            mylist.Add(DirectCast(Dict.Value, String))
        End If
    Next
```

get a random number:

```
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, mylist.count-1)
```

and acess a random memner of the list
    debug.print(mylist(randomNumber))

Comment: Thank you this really helped! Thinking of making a console based login system with this now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use this!

```
    Dim mylist As New List(Of String)
Dim ResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSetrue)
For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In ResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)
    If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is String Then
        Debug.WriteLine(Dict.Key) 
       mylist.Add(DirectCast(Dict.Value, String))
    End If
Next
```